# Drop Down Menu Bottom Space

Tags: css

I’m not that experienced in web design but have hacked this together and seems to be working.  However, I have a small issue I can’t seem to figure out.

I created a navigation drop down menu and in full screen view there is padding between the navigation drop down menu and the page title but, when the screen gets smaller there is no padding.  What is causing this??

Please don’t laugh, here is my jfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/ikeevens/m0njbhf4/
and here is my code.

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #931d03;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #931d03;
  font-weight: 100;
  font: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
h3 {
  color: #003564;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
h4 {
  color: #842200;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0px auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
h5 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h6 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
p {
  margin: 0px auto;
  line-height: ;
  font-size: 12px;
}
sp {
  margin: 0px auto;
  line-height: ;
  font-size: 10px;
}
li {
  font-size: 12px;
}
* {
  padding: 0px auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0px auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  color: #555;
  background: #a6b17a;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#iefix {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
div.container {
  width: 85%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: ;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
div.hsection-inner {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
div.header {
  background-image: ;
  background-color: ;
  padding: 0px auto;
  height: 120px;
}
div.menubar {
  background-image: ;
  background-color: black;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.toggletop,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
  display: none;
}
nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: ;
  background-repeat: repeat-n;
  border-top: 0px solid black;
}
nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
nav ul {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: ;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: ;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover {
  background: red;
  background-image: ;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: ;
}
nav li a:active {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: ;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inherit;
}
nav ul ul li {
  width: 205px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #555;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  left: 205px;
  background-color: #555;
}
nav li:last-child {} li > a:after {
  content: '';
}
li > a:only-child:after {
  content: '';
}
ul.menu {
  width: 100%;
}
div.body-content {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
div.bsection-inner {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 5px 75px;
}
div.section-inner {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  max-width: 1100px;
}
div.footer {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
  height: 75px;
}
div.fsection-inner {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  max-width: 1100px;
}
.clearfix::before {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
.clearfix::after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix {}@media screen and (max-width: 1220px) {
  .toggle + a,
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .toggle {
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }
  .toggletop {
    display: block;
    background-image: ;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
  }
  .toggle:hover {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: ;
  }
  [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav a {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
  }
  nav ul ul .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul a {
    padding: 0 80px;
  }
  nav a:hover,
  nav ul ul ul a {
    background-color: #555;
  }
  nav li:hover > a,
  #nav li a.active {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: ;
  }
  nav ul li ul li .toggle,
  nav ul ul a {
    background-color: #555;
  }
  nav ul ul {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
  nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 0px solid black;
    border-left: 0px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li {
    position: static;
  }
  nav li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0px solid black;
  }
  nav :hover {
    background: red;
    background-image: ;
  }
  div.menubar {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  div.bsection-inner {
    padding: 5px 75px;
  }
  .hide-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
  .hide-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 925px) {
  nav {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: ;
  }
  .hide-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  div.mobile-collapse {
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: none;
  }
  div.body-content {
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
  div.bsection-inner {
    padding: 20px 50px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .hide-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  div.mobile-collapse {
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: none;
  }
  div.body-content {
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
  div.bsection-inner {
    padding: 20px 50px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  div.header {
    height: 100px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6 {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  div.menubar {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  div.body-content {
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
  div.bsection-inner {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  div.mobile-collapse2 {
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  div.header {
    height: 75px;
  }
  .toggle {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  nav a {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  .toggletop {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  .list li a {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  div.ftext {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    font: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 23px;
  }
  .toggle:hover {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: ;
  }
  nav li:hover > a,
  #nav li a.active {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: ;
  }
  #hnavbar ul li a {
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: ;
  }
  div.menubar {
    background-image: ;
    background-color: black;
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  li {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  .indent1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .hide-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
  div.mobile-collapse {
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: none;
  }
  div.body-content {
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
  div.bsection-inner {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .toggletop {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  div.body-content {
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
  #hnavbar ul li a {
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: ;
  }
  div.bsection-inner {
    padding: 20px 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML lang="en">

<HEAD>

  <META content="IE=11.0000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

  <META charset="utf-8">

  <META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <TITLE>Responsive Webpage</TITLE>

  <META name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

  <META name="GENERATOR" content="MSHTML 11.00.9600.18212">




</HEAD>


<BODY>

  <DIV class="container">
    <!-- header -->
    <DIV class="header">
      <DIV class="hsection-inner">

      </DIV>
      <!--hsection-inner-->
    </DIV>
    <!--/header-->


    <!-- nav -->
    <DIV class="menubar" id="iefix">

      <nav>

        <label for="drop" class="toggletop">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Services</label>
            <a href="">Services</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Service 1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Service 2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Service 3</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Service 4</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Service 5</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Products</label>
            <a href="">Products</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2" />
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Product 1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Product 2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Product 3</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Product 4</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Company Info</a>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </nav>

    </DIV>


    <!--/nav-->

    <!-- body-content -->
    <DIV class="body-content">
      <DIV class="bsection-inner">

        <h1>Page Title</h1>
        <hr>
      </DIV>
      <!--section-inner-->
    </DIV>
    <!--/body-content-->

    <!-- footer -->

    <DIV class="footer">
      <DIV class="fsection-inner">

      </DIV>
      <!--fsection-inner-->
    </DIV>
    <!--/footer-->


  </DIV>
  <!--/container-->

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. Be more descriptive of what the problem is. Maybe provide annotated screenshots

Comment: Below is my jsfiddle.  Notice before you select the menu there is padding between the menu bar and page title.  When you click on the menubar that padding goes away.  I want the padding there when the menubar is clicked.

    https://jsfiddle.net/ikeevens/m0njbhf4/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the jsfiddle you provided, you need to remove the 30px height from div.menubar.
It should look like this:

```
div.menubar {
  background-image: ;
  background-color: black;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

**Explanation**:
That way the .body-content know how much space is the menu needed if the dropdown is active.
By putting height on div.menubar, you set a height of the menu and the .body-content will take all of the remaining space.

Hope this helps.